# Regex expression for column

Tags: python

```
Dataframe 
   Ticket       Job
    RQ01    obe_fin_r3_003
    RQ02    ouk_log_r3_002_am

My Objective
```

It is to extract fin, log from the Job column, and create a new one.

```
My Code
df['job_type'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\_\w+)').str[0]
```

This is not giving the desired output, please suggest the regex

Comment: Yes all are working, used the regex one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex you can try this

```
r'\_([a-z]+)\_'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with regex, but you can always use `.str.split()`:

```
df['New'] = df['Job'].str.split('_').str[1]
```

This outputs:

```
  Ticket                Job  New
0   RQ01     obe_fin_r3_003  fin
1   RQ02  ouk_log_r3_002_am  log
```

Comment: Getting KeyError: 'job'

Comment: Fix the column name to fit it to you dataframe. In your example the column was named `Job`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match word characters after the first underscore, you have to exclude matching the `_` itself which is also matched by `\w`

```
[^\W_]+_([^\W_]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ word chars except `_`
- `_` Match the `_`
- `([^\W_]+)` Capture matching 1+ word chars without an underscore in group 1

Using [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) will *extract groups from the first match of regular expression*.

```
import pandas as pd

strings = [
    ["RQ01", "obe_fin_r3_003"],
    ["RQ01", "ouk_log_r3_002_am"]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=strings, columns=["Ticket", "Job"])
df["job_type"] = df["Job"].str.extract(r'[^\W_]+_([^\W_]+)')
print(df)
```

Output

```
  Ticket                Job job_type
0   RQ01     obe_fin_r3_003      fin
1   RQ01  ouk_log_r3_002_am      log
```